# Need to give addresses to google map to show the direction

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to pass two addresses to the following code to show the direction between them based on chosen transportation mode. Once user selects two cities from the Dropdown box in page 1, I am going to send them to the code (page 2) to show their locations and direction between them.

I have copied this [sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-travel-modes) from Google.I am now trying to combine it with my code but do not know how.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Travel modes in directions</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
      height: 50%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #map-canvas {
      height: 200%;
      width:25%;
    }

    @media print {
      html, body {
        height: auto;
      }

      #map-canvas {
        height: 650px;
      }
    }
    </style>
    <script>
 function GetLocation(add) {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var address = add;
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    var output = latitude + "," + longitude;
                    return output;
                } else {
                    alert("Request failed.")
                }
            });
        };

var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var haight = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.81411, 144.96327999999999);
var oceanBeach = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.814107, 144.96327999999994);

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: haight
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function calcRoute() {
  var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
  var request = {
      origin: haight,
      destination: oceanBeach,
      // Note that Javascript allows us to access the constant
      // using square brackets and a string value as its
      // "property."
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel">
    <b>Mode of Travel: </b>
    <select id="mode" onchange="calcRoute();">
      <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
      <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
      <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
      <option value="TRANSIT">Transit</option>
    </select>
    <script>GetLocation("Los Angeles, USA");</script>
    <script>GetLocation("Las Vegas, USA");</script>
        </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass the two addresses to the 2nd page in the query string, you can do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Travel modes in directions</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #map-canvas {
      height: 500px;
      width:600px;
    }
    </style>
    <script>

var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var origin = "Los Angeles, USA";
var destination = "Las Vegas, USA";
var maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
var travelMode = google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING;
var arrivalTime = null;
var departureTime = null;

function initialize() {
  // If there are any parameters at eh end of the URL, they will be in  location.search
  // looking something like  "?marker=3"

  // skip the first character, we are not interested in the "?"
  var query = location.search.substring(1);

  // split the rest at each "&" character to give a list of  "argname=value"  pairs
  var pairs = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
    // break each pair at the first "=" to obtain the argname and value
    var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
    var argname = pairs[i].substring(0,pos).toLowerCase();
    var value = pairs[i].substring(pos+1).toLowerCase();

    // process each possible argname  -  use unescape() if theres any chance of spaces
    if (argname == "origin") {origin = unescape(value);}
    if (argname == "dest") {destination = unescape(value);}
    if (argname == "type") {
      if (value == "m") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;}
      if (value == "k") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE;}
      if (value == "h") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID;}
      if (value == "t") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN;}

    }
    if (argname == "mode") {
      if (value == "driving") {travelMode = google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING; } 
      if (value == "walking") {travelMode = google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING; } 
      if (value == "transit") {travelMode = google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT; } 
      if (value == "bicycling") {travelMode = google.maps.TravelMode.BICYCLING; } 
    }
    if (argname == "arrive") {
      arrivalTime = new Date(value);
    }
    if (argname == "depart") {
      departureTime = new Date(value);
    }
  }

  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
  calcRoute(origin, destination, travelMode, departureTime, arrivalTime);
}


function calcRoute(origin, destination, mode, departureTime, arrivalTime) {
  var request = {
      origin: origin,
      destination: destination,
      travelMode: mode,
  };
  if (travelMode == google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT)
    request.transitOptions = {};
  if (travelMode == google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT && !!departureTime)
    request.transitOptions.departureTime = departureTime;
  if (travelMode == google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT && !!arrivalTime)
    request.transitOptions.departureTime = departureTime;

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else alert("Directions Request failed: "+status);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="panel"></div>

<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
_uacct = "UA-162157-1";
urchinTracker();
</script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_DirectionsFromQuery.html?origin=San%20Diego,%20CA&dest=Los%20Angeles,%20CA&mode=TRANSIT&arrive=6:00pm)

and [working example with form input](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_DirectionsFromQueryA.html?origin=encinitas&dest=escondido&mode=BICYCLING)

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially asking about [SearchBox](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=en) . You don't need it though. You can directly take a form and get the submitted values and Geocode it to be passed in the aforementioned script.